# HKWorkoutSessionManager protocol methods not getting called

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit

I have conformed to my `WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate` and have attempted to update the UI using those protocol methods but nothing in the update function is getting printed or displayed.

My setup requires initialization using `context` and I need to add code to update the `WorkoutSessionManager` when the `context` eventually changes.

How should I update the `WorkoutSessionManager` when the `context` eventually changes?

DashboardController.swift

```
class DashboardController: WKInterfaceController, WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate {

// IBOutlets

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    addMenuItemWithItemIcon(.Accept, title: "Save", action: #selector(DashboardController.saveSession))

    if context is WorkoutSessionContext {

   WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager(context as! WorkoutSessionContext)

    } else {
        print("Context is not WorkoutSessionContext")
    }
}

func saveSession() {
    WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager!.stopWorkoutAndSave()
}

func workoutSessionManager(workoutSessionManager: WorkoutSessionManager, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity activeEnergyQuantity: HKQuantity) {

    // nothing in this function is getting printed or displayed
    caloriesLabel.setText("\((activeEnergyQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(workoutSessionManager.energyUnit)))")
    print("\(WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager?.energyUnit)")
    print("testing print line")

}
```

WorkoutsController.swift

```
@IBAction func startWalkingButton() {
    print("Walking start button pressed")
    presentControllerWithName("Dashboard", context: sessionContext)
    WorkoutSessionManager.sharedManager!.startWorkout(.WalkingButton)   
// no code-completion
}
```

Comment: To create a true singleton the initialization must be private. This can also help you find illegal initializations in your code.

Comment: Did you check that the function is actually being called? (With a breakpoint for example)

Comment: No. I meant a break point to see if it was called at all. If your last print() call is not printing to console than it is not being called at all and the problem is not in the code you have shown here but instead in the code that calls the function.

Comment: Show me the code from where you expect workoutSessionManager(workoutSessionManager: WorkoutSessionManager, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity activeEnergyQuantity: HKQuantity) to be called from

Comment: You must put a call to func workoutSessionManager(workoutSessionManager: WorkoutSessionManager, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity activeEnergyQuantity: HKQuantity) where you want it to be called. Currently there is no call to that function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120887/discussion-between-stephen-kac-and-tymac).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You never called that function and to be able to call that function you must have a reference to DashboardController for you to use in your func startWalkingButton(). Since this is Watch Kit as we discussed above I do not know the best way to do this but Apples Sample Code here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WKInterfaceCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html
will direct you on how to do that properly. If you need help with doing this ask the now more specific question you have.